# Stochastic exponential jump process equality

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I've read in a Paper this equality. However i couldnt find a proof for it. $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\Big\{\int_{[0,{t}]\times E}\ln\left(1+h(s,e)\right))N(dt,de)\Big\}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\Big\{\int_{[0,{t}]\times E}h(s,e)\nu(de) dt\Big\}\right]$ N(dt,de) is a poisson random measure and $\nu(de)\otimes dt$ its compensator. Does anybody have a proof or an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

To prove above equality, we use following Dolean's stochastic exponential $\mathscr{E}(Y)$ of semimartingale $Y$(Please refer to
J. Jacod, and  A. N. Shiryayev, *Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes*, 2ed. Springer, 2003.p.59, **Theorem** 1.4.61),
\begin{equation*}
 \mathscr{E}(Y)_t=\exp\Big(Y_t-Y_0-\frac12\langle Y^c\rangle_t\Big)\prod_{s\le t}[(1+\Delta Y_s)e^{-\Delta Y_s}].  \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

At first, let
\begin{equation*}
  X_t=\int_{]0,t]\times E}e\,[N(dt,de)-1_{|e|\le1}(e)\nu(de)dt].
\end{equation*}
then $X$ is an $E$-valued-Levy process with $X_0=0$.

Next, let
\begin{equation*}
 Y_t=\sum_{s\le t}h(s,\Delta X_s)=\int_{[0,t]\times E} h(s,e)N(ds,de),  \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
where $h>-1$ is a non-random measurable function of $(s,e)$ and satisfies $\nu$-integrable condition, then $Y$ is a process with independent increments, $Y^c=0$,
\begin{equation*}
 \Delta Y_t=h(t,\Delta X_t) \tag{3}
\end{equation*} and
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{E}[Y_t]=\int_{[0,t]\times E} h(s,e)\,\nu(de)\mathrm{d}s, \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
which is continuous in $t$, $Y_t-\mathsf{E}[Y_t]$ and $\mathscr{E}(Y-\mathsf{E}[Y])_t$
are martingales and
\begin{equation*}
 \mathsf{E}[\mathscr{E}(Y-\mathsf{E}[Y])_t]=1. \tag{5} 
\end{equation*}
Now, according (1)--(4),
\begin{align*}
 \mathscr{E}(Y-\mathsf{E}[Y])_t
      &=\exp(Y_t-\mathsf{E}[Y_t])\prod_{s\le t}[(1+\Delta Y_s)e^{-\Delta Y_s}]\\
 &=\prod_{s\le t}(1+\Delta Y_s)\exp(-\mathsf{E}[Y_t])\\
 &=\exp\Big\{\sum_{s\le t}\ln(1+\Delta Y_s)\Big\}\exp(-\mathsf{E}[Y_t])\\
 &=\exp\Big\{\int_{]0,t]\times E}\ln(1+ h(s,e))N(ds,de)\Big\} \exp(-\mathsf{E}[Y_t]).
\end{align*}
\begin{align*} 
&\mathsf{E}[\mathscr{E}(Y-\mathsf{E}[Y])_t]\\
&\quad=\mathsf{E}\Big[\exp\Big\{\int_{]0,t]\times E}\ln(1+ h(s,e))N(ds,de)\Big\}\Big]
        \exp(-\mathsf{E}[Y_t])\\
&\quad=\mathsf{E}\Big[\exp\Big\{\int_{]0,t]\times E}\ln(1+ h(s,e))N(ds,de)\Big\}\Big]\\
&\qquad\qquad     \times   \exp\Big[-\int_{[0,t]\times E} h(s,e)\,\nu(de)\mathrm{d}s\Big] 
\end{align*}
At last, from above equality and (5), get
\begin{align*}
&\mathsf{E}\Big[\exp\Big\{\int_{]0,t]\times E}\ln(1+ h(s,e))N(ds,de)\Big\}\Big]\\
&\quad=\exp\Big[\int_{[0,t]\times E} h(s,e)\,\nu(de)\mathrm{d}s\Big]. 
\end{align*}
which is required.